# If неверно работает: даже если действие выполняется, он говорит иначе

Tags: mysql, php, if

```
if(isset($_POST['newttable']))
                            {
$nname =$_POST['nametableg'];

$new_table=mysql_query("create table `$nname`
(`id_student` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  PRIMARY KEY(id_student)
  )" ) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_query($new_table))
    {
        echo"созданна"; 
    }
    else
    {
      echo "не срзданна.";  
    }
    exit();                 
}
```

Comment: mysql_query($new_table) - эт что?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да вы чего ребят? Первый запрос выполняется, а второй - нет, потому, что таблица уже существует.

1. Забудьте о расширении **mysql**, используйте **PDO_MYSQL** или **MySQLi**.
2. Пишите удобочитаемый код, хотя бы так :

---

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['newttable'])) {

    $nname      =   $_POST['nametableg'];
    #
    $new_table  =   mysql_query('create table '.$nname.'(id_student INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , PRIMARY KEY(id_student))') or die(mysql_error());
    #
    if ($new_table) {
        echo 'создана'; 
    } else {
        echo 'не создана';  
    }
    #
    exit();                 
}

?>
```

Comment: поддерживаю на счет PDO_MYSQL или MySQLi.

Comment: > Криво код вставляет, уж как получилось.

только заметил, что после нумерованного списка некоректно область кода вставляется

Answer (score 2):

```
$new_table = mysql_query("create table `$nname`
    (`id_student` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
       PRIMARY KEY(id_student)
    )" ) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_query($new_table))
```

достаточно странно выглядит:

1) выполняем запрос создания таблицы на основе sql запроса

2) выполняем запрос и вместо sql запроса подсовываем результат предыдущего запроса.

```
 $sql = "create table `$nname`
     (`id_student` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
        PRIMARY KEY(id_student)
     )"
 if(mysql_query($sql))
```

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что таблица не создается. Запрос бы выполнился без проблем. Сделай проверку `if(isset($new_table))`. Это раз. Два. Насколько помню, все SQL-команды пишутся с большой буквы. Посмотри вот [здесь](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) синтаксис. Может поможет